# OAuth2 Flow: Register A User

Tags: oauth-2.0, user-registration

I want to ask this question, because I am not sure if I understood the whole OAuth2 process completly:

The scenario is that you have a app and want to do a registration for a new user inside that app. From the users point view it would be stupid to just re-login after the he created the account.

My idea was to use the "Password Flow" directly and instead of just submitting a password, submit the whole user registration data. But it seems a little itchy to me, so what is your opinion about that?

Answer (score 0):

OAuth 2.0 is a flow to allow **third-party** applications to access end users' resources which are hosted at another service.

In your scenario, both "the client application that accepts a new user's ID and password" and "the service which manages the user registration information" are owned by you. In this case, you don't have to refer to OAuth 2.0 specification. Instead, implement your client application and your web service as you like. If the client application is not yours, you should not allow the client application to accept the user's ID and password directly.

When in the future you think of allowing third-party applications to access your service, it's the time you need to read OAuth 2.0 specification.